# loading data from database JavaScript and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I created a table with the values "$gender, $starte_whight,$end_wight, and 
 $price" which I'm trying to load with ajax and js but I can't get the js script to work with the values of my database, any help will be really appreciated

**this where I select the gender using ajax**

```
 <label for="nombre" class="control-label">gender:</label>

           <div class="form-group">
          <div class="selector-gen">
   <select class="form-control" id="gender" name="clasificacion" required> 
      </select>
           </div>
          </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../ajax/autocomplete/gen.php",
                success: function(response)
                {
                    $('.selector-gen select').html(response).fadeIn();
                }
            });
        });
         </script>
```

**this is how i load the ajax**

```
  $fetch = "SELECT id,gender FROM table ORDER BY gender"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $fetch) or die("no good");
echo '<option value="0">Selec...</option>';
while (($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) {
    echo '<option 
  value="'.$fila["gender"].'">'.$fila["gender"].'</option>';
        }
```

**then I input the wight**

```
  <input class="form-control" id="weight" name="whight"/>
```

**then I call this script**

```
     function Ticket(gender, weight) {
      this.gender=gender;
    this.weight=weight;
         }

    Ticket.prototype.getPrice=function() {
    var price;
     if(this.gender==="gender" && $starte_whight > end_whight){
      price=$price;
    }

     return price;
   }

    $("#calculate").click(function() {
    var genderOptions=[];
      $("select option:selected").each(function() {
        genderOptions.push($(this).text());
       });

       var newTicket = new 
      Ticket($("#gender").val(),$('#weight').val());
      var multiplyVal = newTicket.weight * newTicket.getPrice();
      $("#yourTicket").val(multiplyVal);

      $("#yourTickets").val(newTicket.getPrice().toFixed(2));
      $("#gen").val(newTicket.gender);
   });
```

**this is an example of the script working with default values** 
     https://jsfiddle.net/poojjaval/a9u4mkwy/7

I expect to be able to create any gender value and ranges to a certain price

Comment: check your result from ajax in success function console.log(response); and let us know result

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: what you mean ? did you check your console to see what result is coming ?